# How do I troubleshoot this stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, database-cursor

I wrote a stored procedure, but no matter what I do, the error does not go away.

The MySQL error is:
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE cr CURSOR For (SELECT `id`,`subtitle`,`price` FROM `book`)
...' at line 4

The code I wrote is as follows:

‍‍‍```
DELIMITER //

```
CREATE PROCEDURE show_book()
BEGIN
    DECLARE @id int(11), @subtitle varchar(30), @price int(7)
    DECLARE cr CURSOR For SELECT id,subtitle,price FROM book
                OPEN cr
                    FETCH NEXT FROM cr INTO @id,@subtitle,@price
                    WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS=0)
                    BEGIN
                        Print(@id + ' '+ @subtitle + ' '+ Cast(@price as varchar(7)))
                        FETCH NEXT FROM cr INTO @id,@subtitle,@price
                    END
                CLOSE cr
    DEALLOCATE cr
END //
```

DELIMITER ;

Comment: This is sql-server code much of which is not portable to MySQL and you should not expect such code to port without effort.

Answer (score 0):

Things to fix:

- In MySQL local variables do not use the @-prefix.
- Use separate DECLARE for each variable
- No need to use int(11)/int(7), just use int. They are all the same.
- You should terminate each statement with a semicolon

See the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cursors.html).